# How to persist data without using cookies or database in a Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, session, express-session, data-persistence

So if any client side storage like `cookie` and any persistent database are not allowed to be used. How would you persist data from user input in a Node.js server? `array` is not an option as users should only see their own input. I thought of using `session`(`express-session`), but it essentially uses `cookies` correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use *local storage*.
This package seems interesting: [node-localstorage](https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage)

Comment: hmm thanks but i dont think client side storage is an option.

Comment: Glad to help. So maybe storing data in a text file on the server? And you know, cookies are client side too... I suggest you to make your question more clear with some more explanations of what you try to achiev.

Comment: thanks. I thought about using file but how would you keep a user's data associated to themselves? if user A types 'Hello A', only user A can see 'Hello A'.

Comment: You could use JSON to store and structure your data. Just a simple function may parse it and find your user.